# Multiple launch iterator functoid in Biztalk mapping

Tags: xml, iterator, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

The source file has an identifying value in the field `name`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <line>
        <name>Test1</name>
        <data>data1</data>
    </line>
    <line>
        <name>Test1</name>
        <data>data2</data>
    </line>
    <line>
        <name>Test2</name>
        <data>data3</data>
    </line>
    <line>
        <name>Test1</name>
        <data>data4</data>
    </line>
</root>
```

If I use the iterator functoid in the straight way, I get such result:

[image: Biztalk Mapping]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <line>
        <sequence>1</sequence>
        <name>Test1</name>
        <data>data1</data>
    </line>
    <line>
        <sequence>2</sequence>
        <name>Test1</name>
        <data>data2</data>
    </line>
    <line>
        <sequence>3</sequence>
        <name>Test2</name>
        <data>data3</data>
    </line>
    <line>
        <sequence>4</sequence>
        <name>Test1</name>
        <data>data4</data>
    </line>
</root>
```

How can I fill the sequence field, if it starts from `1` for every new value in the field `name` and continues sequence from the last value if it meets any occured value?
I expected such result in the output file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <line>
        <sequence>1</sequence>
        <name>Test1</name>
        <data>data1</data>
    </line>
    <line>
        <sequence>2</sequence>
        <name>Test1</name>
        <data>data2</data>
    </line>
    <line>
        <sequence>1</sequence>
        <name>Test2</name>
        <data>data3</data>
    </line>
    <line>
        <sequence>3</sequence>
        <name>Test1</name>
        <data>data4</data>
    </line>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterator functoid gets the iteration of the current node - it doesn't look at the text at all.  To achieve what you're trying to do, it'd probably be easiest to use a C# Scripting functoid (which would replace your current iterator functoid) and a `Dictionary<string, int>` to track how many times you've seen a particular name; this would be the contents of the functoid:

```cs
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int> tracker = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>();

public string GetNameCount(string name)
{
    int ct;
    if (tracker.TryGetValue(name, out ct))
    {
        ct++;
        tracker[name] = ct;
        return ct.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        tracker.Add(name, 1);
        return "1";
    }
}
```

Might be a good idea to put it in an external assembly if you'll use it in more than one map (or just for debugging/maintenance purposes).

Doing this in pure XSLT would require some kind of grouping/counting that would likely be far less efficient.